# Histogram Equalization

Tags: python, image-processing

I am a beginner in Python. I want to make a small project on histogram equalisation. Basically I want to include changing contrast, color and crop option etc in my project. I am blank right now. Please suggest something. I am very keen to make this project but how to start?

Answer (score 3):

Python's [PIL module](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) has methods for controlling [contrast, color](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imageenhance.htm), and [cropping](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm).

Comment: Also useful is the `ImageOps` module, with, for example, `autocontrast()` and `equalize()` functions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [PythonMagick](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PythonMagick/). It suports histogram equalization:

```
import PythonMagick
img = PythonMagick.Image("original.png")
img.equalize()
img.write("equalized.png")
```

PythonMagick is not very well documented itself, but its API directly corresponds to [Magick++ API](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Documentation.html). Use Magick++ documentation for reference.

If PIL is enough for you, stick with PIL, it is better supported. I installed PythonMagick from the Ubuntu package, the project page does not open for me.